# Why does Glassfish not recognize the jar?

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, glassfish

I want to deploy a jar on glassfish 4 with the command `asadmin deploy testapp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` in the terminal. The complete layout of the jar is

```
/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
/META-INF/maven/com.test/testapp/pom.properties
/META-INF/maven/com.test/testapp/pom.xml
/com/test/testapp/*.class
```

But every time i get the error

```
remote failure: Archive type of jar was not recognized
Command deploy failed.
```

I compile and package the jar with maven.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems like individual jar's can only be deployed if they contain Enterprise Java Beans.

There are two options to make a class an Enterprise Java Bean.

1. Annotate the class with a component defining annotation from the package `javax.ejb` (e.g. `javax.ejb.Stateless`)
2. Specify the Enterprise Java Beans in the deployment descriptor `ejb-jar.xml` (or `glassfish-ejb-jar.xml` if using Glassfish) packaged in the META-INF directory as illustrated in [5.2 Packaging Enterprise Beans](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/packaging002.htm)

This is a simple example taken from [Simple Stateless with Descriptor](http://tomee.apache.org/examples-trunk/simple-stateless-with-descriptor/README.html)

```
<ejb-jar xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0">
  <enterprise-beans>
    <session>
      <ejb-name>CalculatorImpl</ejb-name>
      <business-local>org.superbiz.calculator.CalculatorLocal</business-local>
      <business-remote>org.superbiz.calculator.CalculatorRemote</business-remote>
      <ejb-class>org.superbiz.calculator.CalculatorImpl</ejb-class>
      <session-type>Stateless</session-type>
      <transaction-type>Container</transaction-type>
    </session>
  </enterprise-beans>
</ejb-jar>
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't deploy JAR files into a Java EE container.  You want to package in a WAR or EAR file, which may have JAR files in its WEB-INF/lib directory.

Comment: Can't you also deploy solitary EJBs?

Comment: It is possible to deploy jar filest. But something is wrong with mine.

Answer (score 0):

As in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33378047/2609399), replace lambda expressions from your code and try again. Will work, I'm sure.

Comment: Please add code to your answer, not just a reference to another post. Thank you